# CSS Font i dot looks weird

Tags: html, css, fonts

I have a problem with the font loading in my CSS.
The problem is that the i dots of the font look strange:
[image: Example]

I use the font Roboto 700. This effect does not appear when using Roboto 500.
When changing the zoom of the browser it looks better, too.

At first, I imported the font this way:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,500,700);
```

In this case there is no problem with the rendering.

As I want to save the fonts on my server I use this code:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('/fonts/roboto-bold-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/fonts/roboto-bold-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 700;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('/fonts/roboto-medium-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/fonts/roboto-medium-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 500;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    src: url('/fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/fonts/roboto-regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
    font-weight: 400;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

With this CSS code I get the output shown in the image above. What is the problem here?

Comment: Are you using **Roboto** font and increasing its font-weight to 700 using CSS or using **Roboto-Bold** font directly from fonts saved on the server-side?

Comment: I guess the font-weight of the regular Roboto font is increased to 700 instead of applying the "roboto-bold-webfont" which I have on the server. Somehow the three @font-face do not apply. I thought I could differentiate the fonts by the font-weight attribute and the browser would be able to automatically choose the right one. I do not want to specify the font-family with e.g. 'Roboto-bold'

Comment: so you got the solution now?

Comment: No. I am still not able get it working with my own @font-face and the sources on my server.

Comment: are your fonts getting applied on the server side using `@font-face` or not? Also, this issue you are facing is for specific browser or for all browser?

Comment: Also, are all of your fonts placed inside **fonts** folder? and is your **css** file and **fonts** folder siblings? This is necessary!

Comment: This issue is not browser related. I tested it in Chrome, Firefox and IE. The fonts are placed inside the fonts folder and I can see that they get loaded correctly in the networking tab. The @font-face is applied correctly, but I get this strange effect, though.

Comment: Okay it seems that I could solve the problem now. I removed some characters from the fonts with FontForge. I guess this has lead to the problem. I downloaded the fonts again and it looks good now. Thanks for your help.